# Add class="active" to html element using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have my header in a php external file, linked to the website pages.
When I click it adds the active class but it doesn't stay active... I have no idea what I'm doing wrong!
Can someone please help me?
This is my code:

HTML (in php file):

```
<ul class="site-header__list">
    <li class="site-header__item">
      <a class="site-header__link" href="index.php">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="site-header__item">
      <a class="site-header__link" href="portfolio.php">Portfólio</a>
    </li>

    <li class="site-header__item">
      <a class="site-header__link" href="empresa.php">Empresa</a>
    </li>

    <li class="site-header__item">
      <a class="site-header__link" href="contactos.php">Contactos</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.site-header__item a').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).sibling().removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: There's no `sibling` method, it is `siblings`

Comment: And when you click on a link, page __reloads__

Comment: ....and this has nothing to do with php

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery(document).on("ready page:change", function() {

  if(window.location.href.indexOf("index.php") > -1 ){ //or You full URL

      jQuery('.site-header__item a').addClass('active'); 
      //or other .site-header__item a 
      //ps. better use id not class or add some one more unique class for every button
      // as this will add class active to all '.site-header__item a'
  }

});
```

And Yes, it's because after on('click') event Your page reload.

Comment: This may work for simple needs, but will fail for anything more complex

Comment: you need to target one of the links, not all of them, and checking for one at a time like that would be a really poor design

Comment: Thank you! I used id, as you suggested, and it is finally working!

Answer (score -1):

The below code will set the active class appropriately when a page loads based on the url of the request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    // Set active state on menu element
    var current_url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
    var full_url = current_url + location.search;
    var $navLinks = $("ul.site-header__list li a");
    // First look for an exact match including the search string
    var $curentPageLink = $navLinks.filter(
      function() {
        return $(this).attr('href') === full_url;
      }
    );
    // If not found, look for the link that starts with the url
    if (!$curentPageLink.length > 0) {
      $curentPageLink = $navLinks.filter(
        function() {
          return $(this).attr('href').startsWith(current_url) || current_url.startsWith($(this).attr('href'));
        }
      );
    }
    // If still not found, look for links that contain the page name only
    if (!$curentPageLink.length > 0) {
      $curentPageLink = $navLinks.filter(
        function() {
          return $(this).attr('href').match(current_url) ||
            current_url.match($(this).attr('href'));
        }
      );
    }
    $curentPageLink.parents('li').addClass('active');
  });
</script>
```

We use this in all our applications and it works perfectly:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work...When you mean url do you mean like: localhost/folder/file.php? or actually www.website.com? I don't have that kind of url, since the website hasn't been published

Comment: @Joana sorry, we use absolute urls on all our menus, yours are relative links. I've updated the above to account for that, please see https://dodsoftware.com/so/active-menu.html as a working example